# MMC - Certificates Snap-In

Tags: certificate, mmc

When I go on a particular server (Win2k8 R2) and add the Certificate snap-in I get prompted to select which account (my user, service or computer) will manage the snap-in. I have used this snap-in countless times and have **never** not been prompted.

Another user at my company logged into this same server as himself (we are both admins on the machine) and instead of being prompted it goes right into the local user account without letting him choose. We want to go into the computer account version.

Has anyone seen this and if so what is the resolution?

Comment: This server part of an AD?

Comment: Has he got a saved MMC session template that he loads, rather than adding it upon opening MMC?

Comment: No he is doing a Start -> Run -> MMC and then a Add \ Remove Snap-In and then selects Certificates.

Comment: I just dbl checked his permissions and apparently he is NOT an admin on the machine. I'm adding him now and suspect that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution here is to make sure that the user is in the local Administrators group. Then the user will be able to access all three account locations.